Can we retrieve entries from a tibble using index matrix?
I have a matrix where the row and column indices are stored that I want to retrieve from a dataset. With a data.frame this works fine:
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a= letters[1:10], b= LETTERS[1:10])
sm <- matrix(c(sample(1:10, 3, replace= TRUE), sample(1:2, 3, replace= TRUE)), ncol= 2)
df[sm]
[1] "i" "D" "g"

But using the same indices matrix to get entries from a tibble fails:
df_tibble <- tibble::as_tibble(df)
df_tibble[sm]

This returns the error Error in df_tibble[sm]: ! Subscript sm is a matrix, it must be of type logical. Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
How to use sm to get the entries df[sm] from df_tibble?  All I came up so far is as.data.frame(df_tibble)[sm]. So does it mean we can not subset a tibble with a indices matrix but have to transfer to a data.frame first?

@Friede Yes, I use some workaround and was simply wondering whether there is a proper way of doing it. Apperently there is none

If you are really intent on not converting tib to a plain data frame then any of these one-liners will do it
purrr::map2_chr(sm[,1], sm[,2], ~ tib[[...]])
## [1] ] "i" "D" "g"

mapply(\(...) tib[[...]], sm[,1], sm[,2])
## [1] "i" "D" "g"

mapply(`[[`, list(tib), sm[,1], sm[,2])
## [1] "i" "D" "g"

Note
Input from question
library(tibble)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a= letters[1:10], b= LETTERS[1:10])
sm <- matrix(c(sample(1:10, 3, replace= TRUE), sample(1:2, 3, replace= TRUE)), ncol= 2)
tib <- tibble(df)


There is a lot to learn for me from this answer. Thank you!

Interesting looping approach, thank you! I expect tibble(quickdf(df2)[sm]) to be faster. What do you think?

Nothing than a work-around:
df2 = tibble(df) 
quickdf = \(l) { # https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html
  class(l) = "data.frame"
  attr(l, "row.names") = .set_row_names(length(l[[1L]]))
  l }
tibble(quickdf(df2)[sm])

Edit
As user @IRFTM mentions in a comment below, if your data is not already stored as tibble, simply do tibble(df[sm]).
Data
df = data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=LETTERS[1:10])
sm = structure(c(9L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L), dim = 3:2)


I thought tibbles inherited dataframe status?  Wouldn’t tibble(df2[sm]) succeed?  (Agree that two column matrix argument to [ seems the obvious extraction method. )

Ahh, obviously, if you mean df.

Yes that’s what I meant.

A work-around using unlist():
pull_tbl_from_mat <- function(tbl, sm) {
  n <- nrow(tbl)
  unlist(tbl, use.names = FALSE)[sm[, 1L] + (sm[, 2L] - 1L) * n]
}

pull_tbl_from_mat(df_tibble, sm)
# [1] "i" "D" "g"

You can also use a logical matrix but that changes the order of the output.
pull_tbl_from_mat2 <- function(tbl, sm) {
  n <- nrow(tbl)
  m <- ncol(tbl)
  mat <- matrix(logical(n*m), ncol = m)
  mat[sm] <- TRUE
  tbl[mat]
}
# [1] "g" "i" "D"

